# Some info about ambient temperature and electronic devices

Tags: cooling, temperature

I live in Greece and the summer is quite hot, it is 36 degrees Celsius right now (mid of July). I wonder if it is safe to operate without interruption (24/7) my devices in such temperatures.

I have a laptop which when I use, the CPU (Intel Core i3) goes from 5% to max 20%.

I have a very old computer (Pentium 4) inside a closet (to limit the noise of the fans), without case. The CPU goes to 5-10% max. Inside the closet with the door closed the temperature of the machine (putting my hand over the power supply) gets quite hot (comfortable to touch but feels hot).

And finally I have an audio DSP rack unit with 17 processors inside, that is fan-less. When the software is closed and the unit is in power saving mode I measured the metal case with a common temperature meter and it registers 36 degrees Celsius. When the software is running it gets hotter.

Now I run the laptop and the DSP rack 24/7 uninterruptible and it works fine, but what about when the ambient temperature reach 40 degrees Celsius? Should I obviate from using the devices and just wait for the external ambient temperature to fall to a more comfortable level or the devices are able to operate on such environment?

Answer (score 0):

For random electronic devices: check the manual for each device. Each one should list an operating (ambient) temperature range it should be fine to work in.

The same goes for laptops and desktops, but obviously it is difficult to tell for certain under constant heavy load. If you have good insulation in an enclosed area or otherwise have restricted airflow then you need to take account of the *local* ambient temperature.

Most electronics will be fine in 40C air, but if you put it in a box without any way for heat to be extracted then you need to measure the temperature **inside** that box or room, not the temperature of the air immediately surrounding you.